# Angular 2: Code reuse between many projects

Tags: angular, single-page-application

What are best practices for sharing code between many angular 2 projects?

I know that one possibility is to use internal npm feed and install packages from there, but this is only if the shared modules are component libraries.

Is it possible to go even further - to bootstap whole application from this internal npm feed (with routing, templates) and customize just some styles and templates probably, but also to be able to extend components behavior if needed?

I know that the question is too abstract, but probably there are some best practices and guidelines to achieve this?